# Showing form from form_load event handler and showing progressbar

Tags: vb.net

Here are some things which I don't know how to do properly in .Net but I'm sure that some solution surely exists.

I have form which is open like dialog and under (that) form_load I have some checks of data and after that I call a procedure which may take 10 seconds to process.
During this time my form is not showed until my process don't finish and I can see some 'garbage of menu' in my main form instead of progressbar in those new form which is in process.

Second thing I see and which may be close to first problem is that in some of my forms progressbar don't comes to end when results of some process is showed but program (for progressbar) is maked properly. It seem's like progressbar work in some asynchronous task.

How to fix those problems and get my form showed before my procedure starts?
How to get progressbar to show a value reliable? Or I can say beter like it works in VB6?

For first problem I try:

```
Me.Activate
or 
Me.Refresh

Call myProcedureWithProgressBar(myArgs)
```

From Form_Load but without results.
Form is showed when my procedure finishes but should be showed before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event `Form_Load` executes the code **before** showing the `Form`. You can create a `Timer` and use this to automatically execute code after form load:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub OnFormLoaded(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Timer1.Enabled = False

    '...
End Sub
```

And make sure you stop the timer on the method like I did, and make sure you prevent user to do something that could interfiere with the execution (clicking buttons, closing form...). Hope it helps.

---

And about the `ProgressBar` issue, I don't know what could be the problem without more information or code. Maybe you can try something like this:

```
Public Sub UpdateProgressBar(ByVal cont As Integer, ByVal max As Integer, ByRef objTarget As ProgressBar)
    Dim dProgress As Double = cont * 100 / max
    objTarget.Value = CInt(dProgress)
    objTarget.Refresh()
End Sub
```

Comment: Interesting trick. I don't understand how it work but it work. I start my process from OnFormLoad, after disabling timer and program behaves OK, like it should be. Now, what to do with progressbar. It comes to about 50% instead to 100%? Problem is that I have to hide them in order to show process resuults. Is here a trick to get it showed "as should be"?

Comment: I don't know why your `ProgressBar` its not working properly. Maybe is something you do. You should share code related to it in order people can help you.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will try to prepare acceptable example in order to ask help. This one is too big and too connected with rest of program to be suitable to post here. I tried Refresh() but still don't work as should.

Comment: Updated my answer with a function that could be useful for you